# It is possible to move the content of 1 row to another row?

Tags: row

I have this data frame:

| biopsia1 |
| --- |
| Name:Juan |
| Rut: 17006-9 |
| Diagnostic: |
| Gallbladder Cancer |

I split the data base in 2 columns

| text | text_2 |
| --- | --- |
| Name | Juan |
| Rut | 17006-9 |
| Diagnostic | NA |
| Gallbladder Cancer | NA |

The original format have de Diagnostic results in a different row (i can not change it), so when i split the data base "Galbladder Cancer" is below diagnosis, but i want it in the same row.

| text | text_2 |
| --- | --- |
| Diagnostic | Gallbladder Cancer |

It is possible to move "Gallbladder Cancer" to the same row?
Thank for your help!

Comment: Consider mentioning what program or programming language you are using.

Comment: Also please show us what code you have tried.